# Simple Speeding Ticket Program

Tags: java

I am doing a simple speeding ticket fine program in Java. When I enter a negative number, my output "Speed cannot be negative. Try again." pops up but the number "$0" also pops up.

How do I write my program so that if I enter a negative value, it just prints out "Speed cannot be negative. Try again." and not both this and "$0"?

Here is my code:

```
public class Speeding {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Enter speed:");
    int speed = IO.readInt();

    if (speed < 0){
      System.out.println("Speed cannot be negative. Try again.");
    }
    if (speed <=60){
      System.out.println("$0");
    }else if (speed > 60 && speed <=75){
      System.out.println("$100");
    }else if (speed > 75 && speed <=90){
      System.out.println("$500");
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: Unrelated note: on your past questions, you should mark answers as accepted if they solved your problem, otherwise less people will be willing to help you in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    System.out.println("Enter speed:");
    int speed = IO.readInt();
    if (speed < 0){
        System.out.println("Speed cannot be negative. Try again.");
        }
   else if (speed <=60){
        System.out.println("$0");
    }else if (speed > 60 && speed <=75){
        System.out.println("$100");
    }else if (speed > 75 && speed <=90){
        System.out.println("$500");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple: **Your second `if` needs to be an `else if`.**

Check your original code with comments added:

```
// This will execute if speed is negative
if (speed < 0){
    System.out.println("Speed cannot be negative. Try again.");
}

// This will ALSO EXECUTE if speed is negative!
if (speed <=60){ 
    System.out.println("$0");
}else if (speed > 60 && speed <=75){
    System.out.println("$100");
}else if (speed > 75 && speed <=90){
    System.out.println("$500");
}
```

And that's what it should be:

```
if (speed < 0){
    System.out.println("Speed cannot be negative. Try again.");
}else if (speed <=60){ 
    System.out.println("$0");
}else if (speed > 60 && speed <=75){
    System.out.println("$100");
}else if (speed > 75 && speed <=90){
    System.out.println("$500");
}
```

#### Why is that?

You currently have two consecutive `if/else` blocks. The first consisting of one `if`, the second consisting of one `if` and two `else if`.
If `speed` is negative, the first block's `if` will trigger - and so will the second block's `if`.

Once you turn the second `if` into an `else if`, however, all of this becomes one `if/else` block. Therefore, if the first conditions triggers, Java won't even look at the remaining part and the code behaves as intended.

#### Alternatively...

...you could change the condition `speed <= 60` to `speed >= 0 && speed <= 60`.
This way, the second `if` will not trigger for negative values anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you have two `if` statements hence when you enter a negative number it triggers this `if (speed < 0)` condition and this `(speed <=60)` condition .

to overcome the problem, you'll need to use an `else-if` block, which essentially means only one statement will ever be executed.

```
int speed = IO.readInt();
if (speed < 0){
     System.out.println("Speed cannot be negative. Try again.");
}else if (speed <=60){
     System.out.println("$0");
}else if (speed > 60 && speed <=75){
     System.out.println("$100");
}else if (speed > 75 && speed <=90){
     System.out.println("$500");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A negative number is less than 0.  It's *also* less than 60.  Just use the same `else if` structure you already use thereafter:

```
if (speed < 0){
    System.out.println("Speed cannot be negative. Try again.");
} else if (speed <=60){
    //...
```

Comment: Got it. Thank you.